# File Manipulation in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I would like to take one large file in javascript and read through it byte by byte and separate every other byte into one file or another but i can't seem to even print out a single byte from a .txt file

```
var control = document.getElementById("your-files");
files = control.files;
len = files.length;
var test = document.getElementById("test");
test.value = "Filename: " + files[0].name;
test.value += "\n" + "Type: " + files[0].type;
test.value += "\n" + "Size: " + files[0].size + " bytes";


var blob = files[0].slice(0, 1000);
test.value += "\n" + blob;

var myReader = new FileReader();
test.value += "\n" + myReader.readAsText(blob);
test.value += "\n" + myReader.readAsBinaryString(blob);
```

I can print out the file size type and name but trying to print a blob i get it listed as just an object blob

example

```
Filename: test.txt
Type: text/plain
Size: 9604 bytes
[object Blob]
undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

All I need to do is to add the file creation now that I can actually use the blobs.

```
function SplitFile(){

    var control = document.getElementById("your-files");
    files = control.files;
    len = files.length;

    var test = document.getElementById("test");
    var i = 0;
    while (i < len){
        test.value += i + "\n";
        test.value += "Filename: " + files[i].name;
        test.value += "\n" + "Type: " + files[i].type;
        test.value += "\n" + "Size: " + files[i].size + " bytes";

        num_files = document.getElementById("piece-up").value;
        test.value += "\n" + "Number of files: " + num_files;

        var file_length = files[i].size;
        var slice_size = 1000;
        var remainder = file_length % slice_size;
        var num_large = file_length - remainder;
        var num_loops = num_large / slice_size;
        var slice_0 = 0;
        var slice_1 = slice_size;
        var q = 0;
        while(q< num_loops){
            var myReader = new FileReader();
            myReader.readAsText(files[i].slice(slice_0, slice_1));
            myReader.onload = function(event) {
                var contents = event.target.result;
                test.value += "\n" + contents;
            };
            slice_0 = slice_0 + slice_size;
            slice_1 = slice_1 + slice_size;
            q++;
        }
        var myReader = new FileReader();
        slice_0 = slice_1 - slice_size;
        slice_1 = slice_1 + remainder - slice_size;
        myReader.readAsText(files[i].slice(slice_0, slice_1));
        myReader.onload = function(event) {
            var contents = event.target.result;
            test.value += "\n" + contents;
        };
        i++;
    }
}
```